# Laravel: Save uploaded file into Session

Tags: php, ajax, session, laravel

Instead of uploading and moving the file directly to a place on the server, I would rather save it into the Session and upload it on a condition at a later point.

Here is my Method that currently saves the File to my server:

```
public function step3store() {

    $file            = Input::file('file');
    $identifier      = date("Ymd") . " - " . Session::get('lastName') . "_" . Session::get('firstName');

    $destinationPath = base_path() . '/uploads/'. $identifier ;
    $extension       = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
    $filename        = $identifier . " - " . uniqid() . "." . $extension;

    $upload_success = Input::file('file')->move($destinationPath, $filename);

    if( $upload_success ) {
        return Response::json('success', 200);
    } else {
        return Response::json('error', 400);
    }

}
```

And I am thinking about using something like this instead:

```
    Session::put([
        'file' => Input::get('file'),
    ]);
```

But whenever I check my Session, after I uploaded a file, I get the value "null" for "file".

Since I am uploading multiple files per Ajax, I am not sure if it somehow breaks the way I put files into the Session.

So, how do I save multiple files per Ajax into the Laravel Session?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you want to that? Storing files in a session isn't a good practice at all, why don't you store them on a temp folder and do a cron job every day to clear it out? This way you can store the temporary location on your session instead the file

Comment: Because I use multistep form. In Step 3 user uploads images. In Step 4 he  pays and only then I wanted to use real server resource and save them actual files on the server that actually correspond to an "order"

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Sessions are for small, trivial bits of data only, not large bits of data and files like images.

Store the image in a directory like normal, then move them to another directory if the user completes the form. Have a “garbage collection” script that runs periodically that cleans any images from the first directory in the case of a user hasn’t completed the form after some time.

Your sentence, “only then I wanted to use real server resource” makes no sense, as if you were to save the file to a session then that would *still* use your server’s resource. Sessions are written to disk. Same thing if you were to store the file to the database as a BLOB (don’t do that either). You’re still using your server’s resources. So the theory of saving the file to the session doesn’t stop using your server’s resources.

Comment: Spent an hour looking for answers. So that's why its not showing when I dump it in a blade file. Thank you so much mate!

Answer (score 5):

This is how you should do it. Storing an entire image in the session is not a good idea. Session cookies can't store big data.

Store the image on the server. Give the image an id. And store that id on the session.

Comment: I'll do that. Your answer was just as correct, so thank you for that.