# How to keep $request data after authentication?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am building an app which allows a user to fill in the form, choose files for upload without authentication.
When a user clicks submit he, actually, posts data to a route protected by auth.
The problem is that if the user was not logged in before the POST, the $request data is lost after entering the credentials.
So, it should work like this:
User submits data ->If user is not logged in->User logs in->User gets to a protected rout with the POSTed $request data.

How to achieve this?
What would be the best approach?

Thanks!

Comment: Best way to do it is to protect the route that has form. Because what is the point of having protected form submit route but not the view route?

Comment: The point is simplify user experience. User gets to the site and places the order. It is necessary to show user what he needs to place the order, without making the user registering and authenticating

Comment: Update your Auth Middleware, and at the time of the redirection, pass your request data in a flash session

Comment: Then you can make a popup for login purpose and after the successful login you can submit the form. It would be easy to handle if you are using APIs. Other than that, did you try saving the request data in session and then use it after authentication?

Comment: A user should upload a file of ~100MB. Basically, do not understand if session data will help me out here...

Comment: Save the file into a temporary place and then ask for log credentials. If no credentials are given, ignore the file uploaded. Then periodically delete temporary files. So you can use this strategy even if the user is not registered and has to create a new profile (I would hate a site that makes me do that kind of things, though)

Comment: Yes, this could be a possible workaround - I've found a similar problem with a similar solution suggested https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28627575/laravel-save-uploaded-file-into-session